# How to insert a newline in JSON data for a POST request?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

**In the following code:**

```
import requests


msg = "Hello.\n\nMy name is John."

payload = {
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": msg
        }
    ],
    "metadata": {}
}

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json"
}

print(requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=payload).json())
```

The `msg` string has many `\n` newlines but when the request is sent, it escapes the backslash. It posts `\\n` for every `\n` in the string...

Apparently raw text can post the newlines correctly without escaping the backslash.

```
payload = "{\"content\":[{\"type\":\"text\",\"text\":\"" + msg + "\"}],\"metadata\":{}}"
```

Is there a way to make newlines work without having to use raw text for the payload (it can be very confusing)?

Comment: I think you're getting confused about where escapes happen…  try doing `print(payload['content'][0]['text'])` and you should see the new lines "unescaped". the server you're posting to might also be handling them incorrectly

Comment: Doing what you suggested returns the correct text. But the server reads it `\\n` instead of `\n` after posting the data. But using the raw string doesn't cause this problem. A server issue?

Comment: at a guess the server isn't correctly parsing the JSON data (the `requests` package is pretty reliable in my experience).  if it's open source maybe ask with them?

Comment: Why do you think, the POST is sent with "doubled backslashes"? I tried your code and it works fine.

Comment: as what it is , i ran server and got `{"content": [{"type": "text", "text": "Hello.\n\nMy name is John."}], "metadata": {}}`